# How to sort 2d numpy array by items in the inner array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of arrays, and would like to sort these inner arrays based off the value of the first element in them, then the third element, and finally the second element.

I tried specifying the order parameter in np.sort, but it gives me an error given this array is not an structured array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]
    ]
)
arr.sort(order=[0, 1, 2])
print(arr)
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "/home/cg/root/6449d16512b77/main.py", line 11, in <module>
   
    arr = arr.sort(order=[0, 1, 2])
    ValueError: Cannot specify order when the array has no fields.
```

Even if I attempt using structured arrays, I get a different output:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 0]
    ],
    dtype=[('a', int),
    ('b', int),
    ('c', int)
    ])

arr.sort(axis=1, order=['a', 'c', 'b'])
print(arr)
```

Results in:

```
[[(1, 1, 1) (2, 2, 2) (3, 3, 3)]

 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 1, 1) (2, 2, 2)]

 [(1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 1) (2, 2, 2)]
 [(1, 1, 1) (2, 2, 2) (3, 3, 3)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 1)]]
```

I would like the output to be like so:

```
[
[0, 2, 1],
[1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 2],
[1, 2, 3],
[3, 2, 1]
]
```

How can I do this with numpy without using structured arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.lexsort` for this. Note that the argument passed to `lexsort` must be in reverse order i.e. it's sorted by the last element first, then second last, and so on.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1], [1, 1, 0]])

print(arr[np.lexsort((arr[:, 1], arr[:, 2], arr[:, 0]))])
```

Output:

```
[[0 2 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [3 2 1]]
```